# Create a nested map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, recursion

In C++, what can I do if I want to create a nested map like this?

```
map<string, map<string, map<string, ...map<string, int> ...> > >
```

I want to create such a nested map recursively, and the number of maps depends on the value of a specific variable.

I tried write codes like this:

```
struct TP;
struct TP:map<string, TP*>{};
```

But the problem is, I cannot put the final `map<string, int>` into it.

Is there any possibilities to do so?

Comment: When is the value of that variable becomes known? Is it a (compile time) constant expression?

Comment: @StoryTeller Before creating the map. It's just something like a user input.

Comment: Then you can't define the static type of the object. What you can do is to define that type as a recursive [variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/variant.html). Where you'd need to constatly check if you reached the leaf.